# Loading PDF Binary retreived from injected AJAX GET in WKWebView to PDFKit

Tags: swift, ajax

I'm trying to intercept an ajax delivered pdf file from an authentication-secured website.  Since ajax delivers the file, the URL does not contain a ".pdf" link for downloading but rather delivers the PDF file as content-disposition attachment.

As of now, when the decidePolicyFor navigationResponse delegate method detects an "application/pdf" mimetype, I call an evaluateJavaScript method with the following code:

```
func readUrlContent(url: NSURL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void) {
    self.evaluateJavaScript("(function() { var result = ''; $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: '\(url)', contentType: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8', success: function(r) {result = r}, failure: function() {result = null}, async: false }); return result })()", completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in
    let result = response as! String
    completionHandler(result)
    })
}
```

With this injected code (which I use because I had issues with cookies and authentication on the website using WKWebView), I can successfully print the PDF Binary string returned as "result" in the completion handler to the log.  The issue now is that I need to get this pdf binary data into a PDF document using PDFKit.

When I take this binary string and do:

```
self.data = result.data(using: .utf8)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pdfSegue", sender: nil)
```

And pass the binary PDF string to a PDFKit ViewController to display it, all pages appear blank and I get the following errors:

> "encountered unexpected object type: 7."
>
> "missing or invalid object number."
>
> "missing or invalid cross-reference stream."
>
> "invalid stream length 3555; should be 6444."
>
> "FlateDecode: decoding error: incorrect header check."

etc. etc. etc.

How/can I get this PDF binary data returned and view it using PDFKit?